# My content disappears when I set the HTML tag to 100% height

Tags: html, background, height, css

I have a vertical layout that I want to remain centered on the page. One column stays fixed on the page while the other should scroll according to the content and there are some decorative floating divs that are absolute. I want the scrolling column to display 100% vertically, even if the content doesn't require the height, but I can't seem to get this to work.  I've set the html tag and body tag to height:100%, as well as all of the necessary div tags. Having the html tag set to this attribute causes all of the content except for .content and .share to disappear.

Here is my html:

---

```
<html>

<body>
<div class="leaderboard"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="share">

<p>All content © 2011 
    <br />
    Web Design © <a href="http://www.unillu.com" target="_blank">Unillu</a>,  Megan Prior-Pfeifer</p></div>
  <div class="sidebar1">
    <img src="assets/llama.png" width="168" height="265" alt="Deathllama logo" />
<ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="howto.html"><img src="assets/phone.png" width="208" height="15" alt="How to put ringtones on your phone!" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="dinosaur.html"><img src="assets/kill.png" width="208" height="31" alt="Kill a dinosaur the easy way!" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="ringtones.html"><img src="assets/ringtones.png" width="208" height="15" alt="Bad ringtones for you to use!" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="legal.html"><img src="assets/legal.png" width="208" height="15" alt="Use the content accordingly!"/></a></li>

    <li><a href="contact.html"><img src="assets/contact.png" width="208" height="15" alt="Talk to me!"/></a></li>

    <li><a href="faq.html"><img src="assets/faq.png" width="208" height="15" alt="Look here before you ask me anything!" /></a></li>

    <li><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/home.png" width="208" height="15" alt="Go home!"/></a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="extraDiv1"></div>
  <!-- end #sidebar1 --></div>

  <div class="content">
  <div class="extraDiv2"></div>
    <p>Contact</p>

    <div class="ads_column"></div>


    <h3 id="text">Contact Brian, Creator:</h3>
    <p id="text"><a href="mailto:brianbritvec@gmail.com">brianbritvec@gmail.com</a></p>


    <h5 id="text">Contact Megan, Webmaster:</h5>
    <p id="text"><a href="mailto:mprior@unillu.com">mprior@unillu.com</a></p>


  <!-- end .content --></div>
<!-- end .container --></div>


</body>
</html>
```

---

And here is my CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Myriad, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.4;
    background-color: #61ADC3;
}
html {
    min-height:100%;

}
 body, .container, .content, .extraDiv2, .sidebar{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

/* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */
ul, ol, dl { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin: 10; 
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px; 
}
a img { 
    border: none;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active, a:focus{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}


.container {
    width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color: #61ADC3;


}


.sidebar1 {
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 224px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #61ADC3;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 32px;
}

.extraDiv1{
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:29px;
    height:609px;
    margin-left:227px;
    background-image: url(assets/sidebar.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    }

.extraDiv2{
    z-index:5;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:-10px;
    width:12px;
    background-image: url(assets/stripe.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: left;
    }

.content {
    z-index:5;
    width: 384px;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: url(assets/gradient.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #FBB03B;

}


/* Hack for IE */
* html .content {
    height: 100%;
}
/* End IE Hack */

.leaderboard {

    width:795 px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #61ADC3;
}
#descriptions {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 170px;
    margin:15px 55px;
}

#descriptions h5 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#text {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 15px 25px;
}

#text h5{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#play {
    width: 25px;
    margin-right:0px;
    float:left;
}




.share {
    z-index:5;
    font-size:9px;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 256px;
    position:fixed;
    float: left;
    color: #F00;
}

.share a {
    color: #C30;
}

#ads_column {
    float:right;
    padding: 5 px 5 px 0 px 5px;
}


.content ul, .content ol { 
    padding: 0 15px 15px 40px; 
}


ul.nav {
    list-style: none; /* this removes the list marker 
}
ul.nav li {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
}
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited { 
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;

    text-decoration: none;

}
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:active, ul.nav a:focus { 
    border:1px;
    border-color: #F30;
}
```

Comment: seconded.  and for what it's worth, Height: 100%; rarely works the way one would expect.

Comment: sorry, thought it was helpful to include everything

Comment: http://www.stupidoutgoingmessage.com/contact.html

This is an example of the problem page. I want the orange to extend all the way down the page. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: when I add height: 1500px (when I specify the amount of pixels) this does work, but using percents doesn't work

Comment: @PeteWilson, this is the only time I've ever seen a person's gender explicitly referred to on this site, and the context for it isn't great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your CSS is a huge mess.

First, avoid using `position:fixed`, especially on such large scale.  Most mobile browsers don't "fix" those positions, and some older browsers render incorrectly with them.

`height:100%` means set the height to 100% of its parent container.  However,  which in this case is "container", which again is sized as 100% of its container, which is "body".  As "body" does not have a height set on it, body's height gets calculated to be enough height to wrap the entire page.

*Note: Setting `height:100%` on body doesn't work to make it scale to the entire window; you have to set `position:absolute` on body and make top/left/right/bottom zero to do that.*

Back to the "body" height calculation.  Notice that the sizing calculation does **not** include anything that is "floated", because when you "float" something, it takes it **outside** of the normal layout.  Anything that is "floated" occupy no spacing!

Try this experiment: turn off `overflow: hidden` in your "container", and you'll see the height of "container" and "body" suddenly collapses into zero.  All your elements are floated, so they take up no space if there is not `overflow: hidden`.

Thus, you whole mess of CSS is essentially telling "content" to size itself to 100% of the height of "container", which is 100% of "body", which is whatever height that is necessary to include all the content of the page.  With `overflow: hidden` in "container", that height is the height of "content".  Without `overflow: hidden` in "container", that height is zero.

If the height of "content" is 100% of zero, which is zero, and it does not itself have "overflow: hidden" set on it, and it is a block element, then this height will simply be ignored and the height becomes whatever height that is required to hold its elements.

There you go.  Now you know why your orange doesn't extend all the way to the bottom of the screen.  You were depending on `height:100%` on "body" to stretch it out to the full height of the screen; it doesn't work this way.

The solution?

1. **DELETE THE WHOLE THING AND TOTALLY REWRITE YOUR CSS** -- It is too much of a mess.  You don't want this.  And it will *never* work right for you.  Get a good book on CSS and read through it, then do it **RIGHT**.  CSS is not something you can learn via trial-and-error.
2. Start with `position:absolute; left:0px; right:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px;` on "body".  This will stretch "body" to fill the whole window.  Check it by setting a background color on "body".
3. Notice that #2 may not work on mobile browsers.  You'll need to set a min-height in pixel value to make sure that it fills the whole screen.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I wish I had more formal training in coding and css, but unfortunately in my design program, they focused more on design, so I am left with nothing BUT trial and error. I've come a long way, believe it or not, and am still practicing, and hope to have the time and money to take a few courses on it in the near future. But anyways, WDM was able to help me. Thanks.

Comment: CSS is very complicated.  There are a lot of traps and pits.  You're constantly pulling out your hair because things don't work the way you expect them to.  And this is *after* you have formal training.  If you do it by trial and error, you are limiting yourself to the simple designs because more complex ones never work for you.

Comment: My suggestion?  There are a lot of very good introductory books on CSS.  Pick one up and read it through.  *Enable* yourself to do more flexible designs.  Don't let the intricacies of the system limit your design freedom.

Comment: I took your advice and rebuilt the page. It looks MUCH cleaner, although I'm sure not perfect. Anyways, the kinks at this point will be much easier to fix.

Comment: Good job.  Welcome to the fun world of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the `.extraDiv2 {height:100%}` which is causing it.

It seems fine in Chrome 10, but very broken in IE9. Try removing the width on the `.container` element and change the float of the `.content` from right float to left float. It may help a little with IE9.

Comment: hmmm...that seems to cause more problems. not sure what that was meant to fix, but it causes my right column to slide under my left

Comment: Which browser/version are you using? Sometimes it is best to strip the CSS back to the basics and start over - try something like the Firebug addon for Firefox (it has literally saved me days of CSS debugging)...

Comment: I'm using Safari v5 and also testing it on Chrome. I'm going to post the link soon so everyone can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: http://www.stupidoutgoingmessage.com/contact.html

This is an example of the problem page. I want the orange to extend all the way down the page. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: The height:100% on the divs is being honoured, it's the body tag that has the problem. Some kind of side effect of the floats, not sure why. This site has helped me in the past with floats: [CSS Positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/). If you don't want to rebuild the stylesheet bit by bit, then my advice is to do as 'wdm' suggests and use jQuery.

Comment: ok. I'll try rebuilding because I'm not sure how to use jQuery, but I'll look up some tutorials. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Height 100% only works if the cointainer block (`html` in this case) has a fixed height defined.
Other than that, I don't see why things should be disappearing.

EDIT: The above is not correct in `html`'s case. (See comments)

In your case **you need to set `html` to `height:100%` (instead of `min-height:100%`)**. That will fix the problem.

I concur with the opinion that the code can be improved, but good job, learning happens step by step.

Comment: really? I've read that if you set it to 100% and all subsequent containers to 100% then it should be fine.

Comment: you are right, as stated [here](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=144).
Sorry for the missinformation

Comment: http://www.stupidoutgoingmessage.com/contact.html

This is an example of the problem page. I want the orange to extend all the way down the page. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: you need to set `html` to `height:100%` (instead of `min-height:100%`)
That will do it.

Answer (score 0):

> "I want the scrolling column to display 100% vertically, even if the content doesn't require the height, but I can't seem to get this to work"

Your best bet is to use some jQuery to set the height dynamically based on the viewport height.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/a2jhw/

EDIT: To show w/ jquery loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        fixHeight();
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        fixHeight();
    });

    function fixHeight() {
        var $h = $(window).height();
        $('#someDiv').height($h);
    }

</script>
```

EDIT: Ok basically here I created a function (fixHeight) where we put the code to fix the height. Then we run the function when the document is ready and when the window is resized.

---

Also here are some fixes for your code...

Closed the comment here.

```
ul.nav {
  list-style: none; /* this removes the list marker */
}
```

Removed the spaces between your numbers and "px" here...

```
.leaderboard {
  width: 795px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #61ADC3;
}

#ads_column {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
}
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">

  $h = $(window).height();

 $('.container').height($h);
 
 $('.content').height($h); 

    </script>`

Comment: This is the code that I added to my page in the header, but it still won't work.  What the heck am I doing wrong?! So frustrating. Thanks for the link though. This will be very useful for me to explore.

Comment: @Megan Are you loading the jQuery library also? I edited my example to show that. Grab jquery-1.5.2.min.js from jquery.com if you don't have it already.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I added that too. So that part of the code is all set up...But I also did a practice page, and I still can't get it to work, so I must be doing something really wrong that I just can't see:

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
#content {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js">
  $h = $(window).height();
 $('#container').height($h); 
 $('#content').height($h); 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">Content</div>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: @Megan I don't think it's going to work with one script tag like that. Check out my example with the two script tags. First one loads jQuery, then your code can go between the second.

Comment: Also I just added the $(document).ready function for good measure (see edits).

Comment: Oh my stars! So I added "html" and "body" to the script and NOW it works. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! But one really funny thing...if the window isn't fully sized, the orange only goes down to the bottom and doesn't resize if you expand the window. Know what that needs?

Comment: @Megan Glad you have it working now. See edits. I added an event listener for window resizing.

Comment: you are an angel. Thanks so much for your help. You have no idea how much I appreciate it. Now I need to take Stephen's advice and sit down with a nice CSS book.

Comment: One minor point: `$h = $(window).height();` should really be `var $h = $(window).height();` otherwise it creates a global variable called "$h".  Also, @Megan, try out the absolute-positioned-body solution as well -- it is simpler, but won't work on mobile browsers while @WDM's script does.